# How to access a long dormant Facebook account

Tags: facebook, account-management, profile

I have not accessed my Facebook account in several years.  Since then my laptop computer and cell phone number have changed.  Thus I am unable to pass the security steps needed to prove that I am who I say I am, update my profile, change my password, and regain access to my FB account. How can I update this info and regain FB access?